# how can I run this code with two loops faster? Can I run it without using for?

Tags: python, function, performance, loops, for-loop

I wanna run this code for a wide range instead of this range. So I wanna make it better to run faster.
Is it impossible to use something else instead of these loops?

```py
    z1=3  
    z2=HEIGHT-1

    def myfunction(z1,z2):  
        for l in range(z1):
            vector = np.zeros(WIDTH)
            vector[WIDTH//2] = 1
    
            result = []
            result.append(vector)

            for i in range(z2):
                vector = doPercolationStep(vector, PROP, i)
                result.append(vector)

            result = np.array(result)
            ss = result.astype(int)
            ss = np.where(ss==0, -1, ss)
            ww = (ss+(ss.T))/2
            re_size = ww/(np.sqrt(L))
            matr5 = re_size
        
       
            np.savetxt('F:/folder/matr5/'+str(l)+'.csv', matr5)
```

and doPercolationStep is:

```
WIDTH = 5
HEIGHT = 5
L=5
PROP = 0.6447

def doPercolationStep(vector, PROP, time):
    even = time%2 # even is 1 or 0
    vector_copy = np.copy(vector)
    WIDTH = len(vector)
    for i in range(even, WIDTH, 2):
        if vector[i] == 1:
            pro1 = random.random()
            pro2 = random.random()
            if pro1 < PROP:
                vector_copy[(i+WIDTH-1)%WIDTH] = 1 # left neighbour of i
            if pro2 < PROP:
                vector_copy[(i+1)%WIDTH] = 1       # right neighbour of i
            vector_copy[i] = 0                     
    return vector_copy
```

Comment: It is not possible to efficiently vectorize generic scalar function like `doPercolationStep` with Numpy without the code of such function. If the outerloop is an issue, I expect the inner loop to be even more an issue.

Comment: I will send the function now

Comment: ` def doPercolationStep(vector, PROP, time):
    even = time%2 # even is 1 or 0
    vector_copy = np.copy(vector)
    WIDTH = len(vector)
    for i in range(even, WIDTH, 2):
        if vector[i] == 1:
            pro1 = random.random()
            pro2 = random.random()
            if pro1 < PROP:
                vector_copy[(i+WIDTH-1)%WIDTH] = 1 # left neighbour of i
            if pro2 < PROP:
                vector_copy[(i+1)%WIDTH] = 1       # right neighbour of i
            vector_copy[i] = 0                     
    return vector_copy`

Comment: Sorry, I can't find the "code format" to write it better than this. hope it will be readable

Comment: It is not (especially for Python where the indentation matters a lot). Please consider updating the question instead (this is the common way to add more information like this).

Comment: you are totally right. I edited the question. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. It is better, but this is still not runnable: some variables are missing like `WIDTH`. The problem certainly comes from the CPython interpreter (which is slow). Python is not really made for such computation. The general solution is to use vectorized Numpy operations. Regarding the probability of `vector[i] == 1` and other conditions, it may not be efficient either to use vectorized calls. Numba or Cython should help a lot here. Note the code will be bounded by the calls to `random.random` and the unpredictability of loops.

Comment: In addition, `np.copy(vector)`  should be replaced with `np.empty_like` since values are not read but only written. Finally, it might be possible to run the code in parallel in Numba/Numpy (but with different results since random functions cannot be parallelized while providing the same output).

Comment: I added WIDTH now. Thanks alot.

Comment: But I still don't get one thing: why the result is different if I wanna run in parallel?

Comment: It seems like you're now asking a question that's entirely different from the question in the text - what exactly is your question? Yes, it is possible to do it differently - could it be faster than your current code? Probably. If you're just asking for a code review, please try the [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). If you have a specific problem with code you wrote to try and improve performance, please post that code with the problem and ask a specific question about it.

Comment: Based on the previous conversation, my question is, does parallelize the current code cause any problems with the results? Or can I technically parallelize my code without changing the result?

Comment: See the previous comment about generating random number I explained above. But as Grisma said, this is a new question that require some new code (and possibly a new question or at least an update).

Comment: Thanks a lot. yes, I got it. First I try to parallel my code and at the end, if something goes wrong I'll ask my question

Comment: One more question: is it a wrong question if I ask how can I parallel this code to run it faster? I tried some ways but they didn't work well.